# Alternative to the globalize gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried out the globalize gem but this seems like a big overhead.  Most of the time I just need one attribute translated.  I'm using postgreSQL and would rather use a hstore for this.  That way I won't get additional tables and performance should be at least as good if not better.

Are there any gems that use this approach or would this mean a custom development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're searching for the **[hstore_translate gem](https://github.com/Leadformance/hstore_translate)**. I have not tested it but it appears to suit your needs precisely from the description:

> Rails I18n library for ActiveRecord model/data translation using PostgreSQL's hstore datatype. It provides an interface inspired by Globalize3 but removes the need to maintain separate translation tables.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the hstore_translate gem and love it.

Say for example you have a Project model schema with `title:string` and `content:text`. If you want `content` to be translated, all that needs to be done is to create a migration:

```
class AddTranslationToProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :projects, :title_translations, 'hstore'
  end
end
```

and inside of project.rb:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  translates :title
end
```

thats it! Nothing else to do in the form or wherever. Works for integers and booleans as well.  The only extra step to do is activate hstore if using postgres: `CREATE EXTENSION hstore`

Answer (score 0):

I've recently created the gem [`awesome_hstore_translate`](https://github.com/openscript/awesome_hstore_translate), which is based on the original [`hstore_translate`](https://github.com/Leadformance/hstore_translate) by Rob Worley.

`hstore_translate` uses `alias_method_chain`, which got deprecated with Rails 5.0.

My gem has the same functionality as it's original, but it's a bit more modern. It stores it's data in columns without a suffix, because I think the database model looks more clean that way. The raw data is still available. E. g. `Page.first.title_raw` will give you the hstore hash.